# Cast no MYSQL X Performance

Tags: mysql, desempenho, cast

Estou tentando melhorar meus SQLs no MySQL e PHP, na analise acabei chegando a uma função CAST está aumentando em pelo menos 5X o tempo de pesquisa como segue abaixo:

Tabela CLIENTES onde o campo DATACAD é DATETIME para guardar data e hora:
Index criado no campo DATACAD

```
SELECT * FROM CLIENTES WHERE (CAST(DATACAD AS DATE) BETWEEN '2021-01-27' AND '2021-01-27')
```

O exemplo acima demora 0,178 segundos

```
SELECT * FROM CLIENTES WHERE (DATACAD BETWEEN '2021-01-27' AND '2021-01-27 23:59:59')
```

O exemplo 2 demora 0,031 segundos

No segundo exemplo estou levando em conta que o cadastros foram criados entre 00:00:00 e 23:59:59 do dia 27 então tirei a função CAST

Me parece que ao usar a função CAST o motor ignora o INDEX do campo em questão, é isso mesmo?

Como montar uma boa Query quando precisamos trazer parte do campo?

Obs: Esses campos já existem a um tempo e já estão bem populados, então separar data e hora é fora de questão :-(

Pode parecer irrisório este tipo de exemplo, mas tenho varias SQLs que usam este tipo de campo e está começando a atrapalhar na performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"Me parece que ao usar a função CAST o motor ignora o INDEX do campo em questão, é isso mesmo?"*

Resposta: não, não ignora, o que acontece é que, para chegar ao INDEX é preciso primeiro fazer a conversão, o que custa tempo, por isso a primeira query é mais lenta.

Para provar isso, repliquei seu cenário e usei o `EXPLAIN` para mostrar os planos de execução de ambas as queries, e ambas usam o INDEX.

Veja aqui: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9DKhXgoXTd4u1yqUf8nXp7/0

Aqui o resultado da primeira e segunda query, na mesma sequência da pergunta:

```
**Query #1**

    EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM CLIENTES WHERE (CAST(DATACAD AS DATE) BETWEEN '2021-01-27' AND '2021-01-27');

| id  | select_type | table    | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra                    |
| --- | ----------- | -------- | ---------- | ----- | ------------- | ------- | ------- | --- | ---- | -------- | ------------------------ |
| 1   | SIMPLE      | CLIENTES |            | index |               | ix_data | 6       |     | 6    | 100      | Using where; Using index |

---
**Query #2**

    EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM CLIENTES WHERE (DATACAD BETWEEN '2021-01-27' AND '2021-01-27 23:59:59');

| id  | select_type | table    | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra                    |
| --- | ----------- | -------- | ---------- | ----- | ------------- | ------- | ------- | --- | ---- | -------- | ------------------------ |
| 1   | SIMPLE      | CLIENTES |            | range | ix_data       | ix_data | 6       |     | 2    | 100      | Using where; Using index |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9DKhXgoXTd4u1yqUf8nXp7/0)

Observe no resultado da coluna "key", ambas as queries tem o valor "**ix_data**" que é o nome do índice que foi criado, portanto, ambas usam o índice.

Agora note que na coluna "type", que mostra o tipo de "join" entre as tabelas. A query não tem join, mas o `WHERE` influencia isso, porque é possível fazer o join usando where, e na primeira query o type é "index" e a segunda o tipo é "range". Se fizer joins nessa query eles serão afetados por esse plano. Veja o que a [documentação do MySQL fala sobre os join-types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain-output.html#explain-join-types):

> - range: Only rows that are in a given range are retrieved, using an index to select the rows
> - index: The index join type is the same as ALL, A full table scan is done for each combination of rows from the previous tables

Se traduzir, o **range** vai restringir as linhas retornadas a uma range baseado no index, e o **index** faz um *"full table scan"*, ou seja, uma pesquisa completa.

Em resumo, se houver joins essa diferença de tempo deve se agravar usando a `CAST`, mas ambas as queries utilizam o index.

Comment: Bacana @Ricardo Pontual, neste caso seria mais "lucrativo" acrescentar a hora "23:59:59" a datafinal para uma melhor performance né? Já que o ganho chega a 5x no meu caso!

Comment: Sim seria, e evitar o CAST. eu acrescentei mais informação, veja que por causa do `CAST`, cada data tem de ser computada, o que tem uma performance muito inferior. Eu gosto muito dessas análises :)

Comment: Que da hora, eu não sou DBA então vira e mexe vou no google ou aqui no Stack pra melhorar minhas pesquisas, e essa dicas foram uma mão na roda, valeu!

Comment: Só acrescentando, você diz então que a melhor forma de fazer select com DATETIME indexado seria colocando data e hora iniciais e finais certo?

Comment: isso, no between usar "00:00:00" até "23:59:59"

Comment: Então @Ricardo Pontual, eu tenho duvida quanto ao COALESCE e IN também, acho que vou colocar um post aqui, exemplo, select * from tabela where (cpf_cnpj in(taxpayer_id, ein)) ou select * from tabela where (cpf_cnpj coalesce(taxpayer_id, ein)), é uma tabela que guarda CPF ou CNPJ em campos separados um dos dois será sempre null, nos meus teste me parece que o IN e COALESCE tem o mesmo desempenho.

Comment: @Marcelo Coloque sua dúvida sobre coalesce em uma nova pergunta, é melhor para o site.

Comment: como o @Piovezan comentou, poste outra pergunta, fica mais fácil para as comunidade encontrar, pois vai ter palavras como COALESCE e IN

Comment: @Marcelo Isso, por gentileza.